# How to create a ligature from a user dictionary in Abby Finereader?

Tags: dictionary, ocr, ligature, finereader

I need to recognize a complex chemichal names from a scanned document (pdf). They contain special characters and are written in a table format. I also have an Excel document that contains ALL possible names (I would say rows because there are no combinations) that I may encounter during scanning. Is there a way to create ligatures (so the Finereader will recognize an entire row instead of dissecting it into separate characters)? I tried creating a user dictionary but Finereader does not treat it as a one row.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to create ligatures is to use "user pattern training".  In FineReader, go to Tools -> Options -> Read tab (changes slightly depending on FR version) and enable User pattern training.  During training extend your box to include several combined characters, thus creating a ligature.

The formulas recognition using this method is tough but may be possible.

I have done this many times in my work at [www.wisetrend.com](http://www.wisetrend.com).  I am a former ABBYY support employee and current integrator and OCR consulting specialist.  I will be glad to help if you need more specific assistance.

Comment: Thank you! Should I always use only user pattern that I've trained or a combined mode with a built-in patterns? Once I'm in a verify mode I correct the same mistake again and again (30Mg  Name changes to 3OMgName). Is there a way to make finereader memorise it?